# Recursive call not in tail position when using for comprehensions

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or it is just a property of the Scala compiler - I get the mentioned compilation error when I try to compile this code:

```
@tailrec
def shiftDown2(x: Int, bound: Int) {
  val childOfX = chooseChild(x, bound)
  for (child <- childOfX) {
    swap(x, child)
    shiftDown2(child, bound)
  }
}
```

whilst the following code compiles without problems:

```
@tailrec
def shiftDown(x: Int, bound: Int) {
  val childOfX = chooseChild(x, bound)
  if (childOfX.isDefined) {
    swap(x, childOfX.get)
    shiftDown(childOfX.get, bound)
  }
}
```

I believe that above code fragments are semantically the same and both should work with tail recursion.

Comment: What's `chooseChild` and `swap`?

Comment: That's not relevant for the question whether this code is actually tail-recursive ghik.

Comment: @BasvandenBroek Yes, but it would make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tail recursion optimization will not work with recursive invocations inside `for` loop, because `for` loop here is just a syntactic sugar for calling `foreach` higher-order method. So, your code is equivalent to:

```
@tailrec
def shiftDown2(x: Int, bound: Int) {
  val childOfX = chooseChild(x, bound)
  childOfX.foreach { child =>
    swap(x, child)
    shiftDown2(child, bound)
  }
}
```

`scalac` can optimize tail calls only if recursive method is tail-calling itself directly - by translating it into something similar to `while` loop in bytecode.

Unfortunately, this is not  the case here - `shiftDown2` calls `childOfX.foreach` passing it an anonymous function. Then, `foreach` (potentially) calls `apply` on that anonymous function and that anonymous function finally calls `shiftDown2` again. So this is an indirect recursion and cannot be optimized by `scalac`. This limitation has its roots in the JVM, which doesn't have native tail call support.

Comment: Nice one. Martin Odersky also explains this well in his 'Functional Programming' Coursera course btw.