# Tail recursion in Scala when flatMap is involved

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, flatmap

I have to use a structure that needs iteration over a list inside another list recursively 
(a structure similar to that used in creating frequent items from a list of transactions). 
Below is the pseudocode.

I get an error saying iterRecur below is not tail recursive. The tail recursion error points to flatMap line below `seqElem <- this.mySeq`
Can you please suggest how I can fix the code?

```
trait SeqElem[T] {
  name: String
  children: List[Node[T]]

class Structure[T](mySeq: List[SeqElem[T]])  {

  def getStructure(node: Node[T]): this.type = {
    ...
  }

  def iterRecur(leastCount: Long, listA: List[T]): Unit = {
    val sumSeq = 
    for(
      //@tailrec annotation points this as causing problem
      seqElem <- this.mySeq;
      node <- seqElem.children;
      if seqElem.count > leastCount
    ){
      val newStructure = getSubstucture(node)
      if (newStructure.mySeq.length > 0){
        newStructure.iterRecur(leastCount, listA ++ List(seqElem.name))
      }else{
        println(listA)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive call not in tail position when using for comprehensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198690/recursive-call-not-in-tail-position-when-using-for-comprehensions)

Comment: Hmm. I was under the impression for-comprehensions translated to map and flatmap and that they were both tailrecursive. Probably I am wrong.

Comment: Whether `map` and `flatMap` are implemented in a tail-recursive manner, or not, is immaterial.  Your method is tail-recursive if it calls itself from the tail position in the code.  In this case `iterRecur` isn't recursive at all. The code is not calling itself, it calls the `iterRecur` method on a different object, the `newStructure`.

Comment: Yeah, thats probably it. It's the same thing mentioned in the post linked by @fede

Comment: The for is basically keeping state (where you are in the List) while calling iterRecur recursively. So it can't be tail-recursive. If you want to make it so, you need to manage this state (how far you are through the list) explicitly, and pass it on to the recursive call. I think you might find it instructive to actually write this in terms of map/flatMap (i.e.. desugar the for) and it will be come clearer..

Comment: Providing non-working "pseudocode" makes it very difficult to offer help. Something simple that could be pasted into the REPL would be better. It is difficult to understand how looping through "this.mySeq" for each recursion ever works.